# Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:

Tags: firebase, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 trying to get Firebase to work based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvzuhkEtGPg&index=1&list=PLMEbEXZJWgoR4GAnwXq2mwk9G6ssheukP) but with Ionic rc4. Any help appreciated.

> ```
> Your system information:
>
>  ordova CLI: 6.4.0
> Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
> Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47
> ios-deploy version: Not installed
> ios-sim version: Not installed
> OS: Windows 10
> Node Version: v6.9.2
> Xcode version: Not installed
> ```

There are no compile errors, but I get the following run-time error:

> ```
> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
> 'h7' is not a known element:
> 1. If 'h7' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'h7' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
>       </h2>
>       <p class="chat-text">{{item.chat_text}}</p>
>       [ERROR ->]<h7 class="chat-time">{{item.timestamp | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h7>
>     </ion-item>
>   </ion-list>
> "): HomePage@23:6 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
> 'h7' is not a known element:
> 1. If 'h7' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'h7' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
>       </h2>
>       <p class="chat-text">{{item.chat_text}}</p>
>       [ERROR ->]<h7 class="chat-time">{{item.timestamp | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h7>
>     </ion-item>
>   </ion-list>
> "): HomePage@23:6
> Stack trace:
> TemplateParser</TemplateParser.prototype.parse@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20796:19
> RuntimeCompiler</RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileTemplate@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45698:30
> RuntimeCompiler</RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileComponents/<@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45618:56
> ```

It seems to be referencing `HomePage`, but I am not sure if it has any errors.
**home.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {LoginPage} from '../login/login';
import {
  FirebaseAuth,
  AngularFire,
  FirebaseListObservable
} from 'angularfire2';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  firelist: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  chat: any;
  constructor(public nav: NavController, public af: AngularFire, public auth: FirebaseAuth) {
    this.firelist = this.af.database.list('/chat', { //mengambil data
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp', //order dari data yang terbaru
      }
    });
  }

  chatSend(va, vi) { //mengirim pesan chat
    this.af.database.list('/chat').push({ // menambahkan data chat ke firebase
      uid: window.localStorage.getItem('uid'),
      img: window.localStorage.getItem('photoURL'),
      username: window.localStorage.getItem('displayName'),
      chat_text: va.chatText,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      negativtimestamp: -Date.now() //buat nanti ambil data yang terbaru
    })
    this.chat = '';
  }

  logout() { // melakukan logout
    window.localStorage.removeItem('email'); // remove email dari localStorage
    window.localStorage.removeItem('uid'); // remove uid dari localStorage
    window.localStorage.removeItem('displayName'); // remove displayName dari localStorage
    this.auth.logout();
    this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);// kembali ke halaman LoginPage
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the error. It is code I download from a tutorial. I see the html has a <h7> tag.  I will modify it and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The h7 tag just doens't exist in HTML 5. This is your error. This isn't an ionic or firebase error. Just change h7 for h6 or some other tag and this error will disapear

Answer (score 3):

Converting to answer: you have a tag in your template that does not make it through the parser, that tag being

```
<h7>
```

Change it to

```
<h3>
```

for instance, and it should work (or put it in a div and style it as you want with a CSS class).